# Grouping & Visualizing cumulative features in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset has shown below. Each product (P*) has a certain feature (F*) on/off (1/0). I'm not able to format the table well.

```
Product   F1   F2   F3  F4  ....
P1        1    0    1   1
P2        0    1    1   0
P3        1    0    1   1
P4        0    0    0   1
..
..
Total     2    1    3   3
```

I have two questions. One related to creating a summary as described below and the next is visualizing this data.

**1) Summarizing:** 
Given this dataset, I want to get the sum of Products for every combination of Features that are On (1). Example:

```
F1,F3,F4 = 2 i.e F1,F3,F4 are present in 2 products P1,P3.
F3,F4 = 2 i.e F3, F4 are present in 2 products P1,P3
F1, F2 = 2
F1, F4 = 2
```

In my actual dataset the number of features are around 200 and number of products are like 10k+. To optimize the calculation, I don't mind providing a threshold for the percentage of Products that have a certain feature. What I mean by that is, from the example given, lets say my threshold is 50%, and there are 4 Products, so any feature that is On for more than 50% i.e 2 is considered for the grouping and in this case it will be Feature F1, F3, F4. F1 is not considered because its column sum is < 2.

**2) Visualization:** 
I was thinking of visualizing this result in a bar chart. Feel free to suggest if there are better ways to visualize this.

My Approach: I am new to R and statistics but well versed in C#.

1. Compute the sum for every Feature.
2. For each set of sums starting from the highest count determine all the Products that have this Feature On. From the sample dataset above: F3, F4 have a max count of 3 (within threshold), so get all the Products that have F3, F4 On. Next (max count - 1) 2 which would be Feature F1,F3,F4 and get all the Products that have these Features On. Do this until the threshold is met.

I am in the process of learning to write this code so no code sample yet to share.

I believe my approach is computationally expensive considering the dimensions of my dataset and believe there might be better ways of achieving this. Thank you in advance for your effort.

Comment: As it stands this question is too broad: you are asking multiple questions, and an answer would take the form of a long tutorial not well suited for this format. I will say that the dplyr tools and ggplot2 visualization package are designed for exactly this type of problem, and would recommend reading this for an explanation: http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf

Comment: If I understand this you have up to 200 features and you want to sum every unique combination of 1 or 0 for these 200. That should be 2^200 possible combinations which is over 10^60.  If that is the case I don't think this is a do-able project.

Comment: Thanks David & John, for your time. I'll explore the dplyr tools. Yes, i agree it's computationally expensive to perform this, just wanted to get a feedback & bounce off ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give you an idea how to vizualize things.

```
# reading your example data
df <- read.table(text="Product   F1   F2   F3  F4
P1        1    0    1   1
P2        0    1    1   0
P3        1    0    1   1
P4        0    0    0   1", header=TRUE, strip.white=TRUE)

# reshape the data from wide to long format
require(reshape2)
df2 <- melt(df, id="Product")

# creating a barplot
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(df2, aes(x=Product, y=value, fill=variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

which gives:
[image]

Comment: Thank you Jaap for answering my Visualization query. Apart from that, the reshape API helped me discover new things.