# Plot multiline graph with custom x axis in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, reshape2

I don't have much experience with R and since I am trying to create a fairly specific graph in R, I hope some of you can help me out.

I have data of the results of four classifiers being used on five different datasets. To get an accurate result each classifier was run on the same dataset 10 times. So now I have a table of the results as following:

```
              DataSet1 DataSet1 DataSet1 ... DataSet2 DataSet2 ...
Classifier1     0.6      0.5      0.7           0.3      0.2
Classifier2     0.4      0.5      0.6           0.6      0.7
```

And so on.
What I am trying to get for my graph is to have four seperate graphs in different colors representing the four Classifiers. The y axis would just represent the results of the classifications and the x-axis should portray the five different datasets. 
Each "mark" on the x-axis should be one dataset and the point on the y-axis for each graph would be the mean value of the 10 results for that classifier on that specific dataset.

I have tried using ggplot2 to achieve this by creating a data frame out of the data and melting it with the dataset names as variables. I might not truly understand what melting really does.

I am not very familiar with creating graphs and plots and apologize if my description is clumsy and lacking.
I would appreciate any help greatly.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, sharing the data via `dput()`. Please read the R tag description, "How to Ask". and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Comment: [This might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23276846/grouping-visualizing-cumulative-features-in-r).

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** Reformat input data + ggplot with [facets](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Facets_(ggplot2)/)

### Input

Since test data wasn't provided, I created dummy data

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)
dummydata <- 
  matrix(
  data = sample(do.call("c", select(iris, -Species)), 10*5*4, replace = T),
  nrow=4, ncol=10*5
  )
rownames(dummydata) <- paste0("Classifier", 1:4)
colnames(dummydata) <- rep(paste0("DataSet", 1:5), each=10)
dummydata
```

Here, dummydata is a matrix that looks like

```
#             DataSet1 DataSet1      ... (x10 total columns of each Dataset) ... DataSet5
# Classifier1      3.1      5.6      ...
# Classifier2      2.8      1.3      ...
# ...
# Classifier4      1.3      ...
```

#### Reformat input to a workable state

1. Make sure column names are unique
2. Make sure object is a data frame
3. Make sure there is a column for the row name
4. Make the data frame long (to be used by ggplot)

We do so by:

```
## Make col names unique
colnames(dummydata) <- paste(colnames(dummydata), 1:10, sep="_")

dummydata_reformat <- 
  dummydata %>%
  ## make sure it is data frame
  ## with a column for the classifier type i.e. rowname
  as.data.frame() %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column("classifier") %>%

  ## reformat data
  gather(dataset,value,-classifier) %>% 
  separate(dataset, into=c("dset", "x"), sep="_")
```

The data now looks like

```
#> dummydata_reformat
#   classifier     dset x value
#1 Classifier1 DataSet1 1   3.1
#2 Classifier2 DataSet1 1   2.8
#3 Classifier3 DataSet1 1   1.6
#  ...
```

### Plot

```
## Plot
dummydata_reformat %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=dset,
             y=value
             ## can add: "color = classifier" to color by classifier
             ## but since you are splitting the plots by classifier,
             ## this does not make sense
             )) +
  geom_point() +
  xlab("") +
  facet_wrap(~classifier) +
  theme(
    ## rotate the x-axis to fit text
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1, vjust=0.5)
  )
```

[image]